# Port that we bind in server is not same as with netstat

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

In the server program I'm binding IP 127.0.0.1 and port 1234.

However when I use netstat -lntpu to find what process is listening to what port..I find my server program listed but strikingly the port number is not what I've assigned !

Here's the line what I'm referring to

```
Proto | Recv-Q | Send-Q | Local Address    |     Foreign Address  | State  | PID/Program_name 

tcp   | 0      |  0     | 127.0.0.1:53764  |       0.0.0.0:*      | LISTEN |   10545/server
```

So if I binded the socket with 1234 why is the netstat listing 53764 ?

I'm able to transfer data successfully from client to server and back. But this is looking strange here !!

Here's the binding code

```
struct sockaddr_in ser_addr

ser_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
ser_addr.sin_port=1234;
ser_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

sd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
ret=bind(sd,(struct sockaddr*)&ser_addr,sizeof(ser_addr));
listen(sd,3);
```

Comment: Please show us your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to to do with the byte ordering of your port setting.

The value `1234` is made up of the two octets `{4, 210}` while `{210, 4}` gives you your `53764` value <sup>(a)</sup>.

When specifying the port address, you should be aware that it is a `16-bit port number, network byte ordered` (from **W. Richard Stevens'** *UNIX Network Programming* <sup>(b)</sup>). Network byte ordering is a big-endian scheme whereas your implementation appears to have a little-endian scheme, hence you need to switch the octets around:

```
ser_addr.sin_port = htons (1234);
```

In fact, you should do it that way even if the byte ordering is the same since it becomes, in that case, a no-operation. The `htons` is how you (quoting from the same book mentioned above) "convert host-to-network, short integer".

---

<sup>(a)</sup> This is so because the order of the octets within a data type dictate how the value is calculated:

```
  4 * 256 + 210 =  1234  // or use (x <<   8 | y) rather than 
210 * 256 +   4 = 53764  //        (x *  256 + y) if you wish
```

---

<sup>(b)</sup> A book you really should have if you're going to be doing any serious networking development.

Comment: Thank you ! I've used inet_addr which coverts into network's Big Endian format while I completely forgot about the port. Is there any function like inet_addr ?

Comment: @RHLK, yes, it's the `htons` call. It won't take a string but it doesn't have to since the port isn't a possibly complex dot-address.